# Acronym, do you use them? And Why?

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style, acronym

Personally I think it's a bad practice in software development (See Clean Code by Robert C. Martin).  But I'm curious to know why people still use them.

I'm talking about acronyms in filenames, variable names, class names, function names, etc.

If you answer, please specify the context (Ex: language, big/small company).

EDIT: I'm not talking about technical acronyms that are common knowledge (ex: sql, html, css, etc.), but rather acronyms within a business.

Two examples:

1) putting two letters which represent the company before each class name

```
SuperCompany: SCNode, SCObject
```

2) a specific module name

```
Graphic: GRTexture, GRMaterial
```

Comment: I am part of A.A.A.A.A. :-)

Comment: @magallanes: ...Annoying Acronym Abuse Addicts Anonymous?

Comment: @MichaelMadsen, thought it was Asinine Addicts Abusing Ambiguous Acronyms?

Answer (score 4):

There is no correct answer to this question, but it is my opinion that you should only use an acronym if another programmer immediately knows it's expansion or meaning. Common examples would be names like `dvdPlayer` or `cssClass`, where a longer version would decrease the readability of your code.

If you are in doubt, don't use acronyms, but don't call your class `HypertextTransferProtocolRequest` instead of `HttpRequest`, because of a strict no-acronym codex.

Answer (score 1):

Context:  Medium Company

Field:  Medical Engineering

 Languages:  Python, JavaScript, C/C++, Perl, etc. etc.

There are lots of reasons NOT to use acronyms in your source code, but in our situation we are gated/regulated by the FDA and several other government agencies that require us to put non-code relevant comments throughout our entire "system" (for auditing/documentation purposes) -- I can't see how we could get through this process without using acronyms.

On the flip-side:  if I was given the choice, I'd not add 90% of what they require us to add to our source code, which would effectively eliminate all the esoteric ambiguity (acronyms and regulation tracking numbers) in our code.

So, YES, I use them, NO, I'd prefer not - but my industry requires it.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that 'clean code' says anything about acronyms? i think it says about readability. acronyms not always are unreadable and meaningless. there are at least two cases when acronyms are necessary.

one is a technical language that is well understood by other programmers (css, html, DAO, DTO, regExp, sql etc) you shouldn't avoid them, they are first class citizens. try to replace them and you will have a lot misunderstandings with other developers.

second rule is: use same language that your clients use. they won't change the names they use. they have their own acronyms (as we have SQL, CSS etc). if you start to change it in your code, you will quickly have a lot of misunderstandings with business